# Header Button's text/font-weight changing unintentionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I am making a header for a page, but from some point I noticed that the text-family is being changed when the dropdown menu was being launched(Safari 8). Then I tried to open it in Chrome, where it didn't changed when launching jQuery function. But when I tried to change the font, but it didn't make any difference. It did't changed the font at all. So even though I don't have specified the font for the header tabs, it's still formatted. Thanks in advance for help. I am sorry if it's just some manor mistake, I am quite new to this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.hdr-drpdwn-menu').hide();
 $('.hdr-list-more').hover(
  function() {
   $(this).find('.hdr-drpdwn-menu').stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
  },
  function() {
   $(this).find('.hdr-drpdwn-menu').stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
  }
 );
});
```

```css
/* RESETTING ALL MARINGS, PADDING AND TEXT-DECORATIONS */
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
ul, li, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, button {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
 background-color: transparent;
}
ul, li {
 list-style: none;
}
a, a:active, a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#header {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #5a5a5a;
 font-style: normal;

}
#header .hdr-nav-opt {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
 background-color: transparent;
}
#header .hdr-nav-soc {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.hdr-nav-list .hdr-list-tab{
 display: inline;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.hdr-nav-list .hdr-list-tab .hdr-button {
 height: 40px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 background-color: transparent;
}
.hdr-nav-list .hdr-list-tab .hdr-button:hover {
 background-color: #7D7D7D;
}
.hdr-drpdwn-menu {
 position: relative;
 width: 120px;
 margin-left: 40px;
 background-color: #5a5a5a;
 box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #888888;
 border: 1px solid #888888;
} 
.hdr-drpdwn-menu .hdr-button {
 width: 100%;
 height: 40px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 5px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- The Global Header of the website-->
<div id="header">
<!-- The Left part of the header-->
 <div class="hdr-nav-opt">
  <ul class="hdr-nav-list">
   <li class="hdr-list-tab"><a class="hdr-list-link" href="?page=home"><button class="hdr-button">Home</button></a></li>|
   <li class="hdr-list-tab hdr-list-more"><button class="hdr-button">More</button>
   <!-- The Dropdown Menu-->
    <div class="hdr-drpdwn-menu">
     <ul class="hdr-drpdwn-list">
      <li class="hdr-menu-tab"><a class="hdr-list-link" href="?page=about"><button class="hdr-button">About</button></a></li>
      <li class="hdr-menu-tab"><a class="hdr-list-link" href="?page=help"><button class="hdr-button">Help</button></a></li>
      <li class="hdr-menu-tab"><a class="hdr-list-link" href="?page=credits"><button class="hdr-button">Credits</button></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<!-- The Right part of the header-->
 <div class="hdr-nav-soc">
  <ul class="hdr-nav-list">
   <li class="hdr-list-tab"><a class="hdr-list-link" href="#"><button class="hdr-button">Facebook</button></a></li>|
   <li class="hdr-list-tab"><a class="hdr-list-link" href="#"><button class="hdr-button">Twitter</button></a></li>|
   <li class="hdr-list-tab"><a class="hdr-list-link" href="#"><button class="hdr-button">Instagram</button></a></li>|
   <li class="hdr-list-tab"><a class="hdr-list-link" href="#"><button class="hdr-button">Tumblr</button></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. When you say "text-family" do you actually mean "font-family"?  Also, where are you applying a font-family to your menu? See: [MDN: font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family)

Comment: Why would you use button inside a link?

Comment: probably unrelated but still, jQuery 1.3.1 could really use an update!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which font you are using now, but maybe you need a callback in your styles

```
.hdr-drpdwn-menu .hdr-button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;/*like this*/
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

and it will works all the browsers.

Comment: the problem is that even though I haven't got the font-family specified, it is still not using the default one

Comment: can you show your code? just to see where is  you are calling the font